# Open GL transformations

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, transformation

I have a small open GL application I'm writing in Java using JOGL.

I'm bashing my head against the wall trying to find the CURRENT way of applying transformations

Essentially what I'm trying to accomplish is to have two objects next to each other. Basically I create objects (methods that calculate all the triangles - i know this is working because both objects show up, they're just overlapping each other), then in display I put them in VBO and call drawElements. My issue is that I can't see to find any examples or tutorials online that DON'T use glTranslatef, glRotatef, and glScalef, which I've been informed is outdated and used to be part of the fixed function aspect of old open GL.

EDIT: (previous code removed)

Epic fail on my behalf. When he said his shader code, i thought he meant the .java file that loads and compiles the shader. It just hit me that he meant the SHADER CODE, which was in a glsl file. I see now where he has 3 mat4 variables which hold rx, ry, and rz. Weird thing is that even if I SET UP a scale and translate matrix, my shapes no longer appear. The rotation matrices are set up as one would assume, and the last line is "glPosition = rz * ry * rx * vPosition;" I tried declaring translation and scale matrices as well and then doing "= s * t * rz * ry * rx * vPosition", but no dice.

Here is the current shader code:

```
attribute vec4 vPosition;
uniform vec3 theta;
uniform vec3 trans;
uniform vec3 scale;

void main()
{
// Compute the sines and cosines of each rotation
// about each axis
vec3 angles = radians (theta);
vec3 c = cos (angles);
vec3 s = sin (angles);

// rotation matricies
mat4 rx = mat4 (1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 
                0.0,  c.x,  s.x,  0.0,
                0.0, -s.x,  c.x,  0.0,
                0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0);

mat4 ry = mat4 (c.y,  0.0, -s.y,  0.0, 
                0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,
                s.y,  0.0,  c.y,  0.0,
                0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0);

mat4 rz = mat4 (c.z, -s.z,  0.0,  0.0, 
                s.z,  c.z,  0.0,  0.0,
                0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,
                0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0);

//mat4 t = mat4 (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, trans.x, 
//               0.0, 1.0, 0.0, trans.y,
//               0.0, 0.0, 1.0, trans.z,
//               0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

//mat4 s = mat4 (scale.x, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
//               0.0, scale.y, 0.0, 0.0,
//               0.0, 0.0, scale.z, 0.0,
//               0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

gl_Position = rz * ry * rx * vPosition;
//gl_Position = s * t * rz * ry * rx * vPosition;
}
```

So essentially, if I uncomment the bottom two matrices, but leave the glPosition statement the same, nothing appears. Also the commented out glPosition statement didn't work (though I'm not surprised, I'm not too great at matrix multiplication). I also tried doing just s * vPosition just to try and only scale, but again nothing is visible.

Comment: Yes this is an assignment for a computer graphics class. Most of the assignment was learning the openGL commands for displaying triangle meshes (i.e. creating a VBO and sending it to the gpu rather than glBegin() and glEnd()) However he gave us no insight into how we should approach transformations. From my internet searches, everything pointed to using glRotatef etc. But when I asked him about it today, he said that was an old standard and now it's controlled by shaders. However, there is nothing in his shader program code that handles it, and he's terrible at responding to emails.

Comment: "I can't see to find any examples or tutorials online that DON'T use glTranslatef, glRotatef, and glScalef" [Did you look?](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_started#Tutorials_and_How_To_Guides) They may not be using JOGL, but you should be able to translate them well enough. The first five of those use pure shader-based tech.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Between datenwolf's link and a few other resources I found, I was able to write a (rather barebones) column-major order matrix class for use in my assignment. I'm posting the source here in case any one else finds it useful.

import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

```
public class CGMatrix {

public CGMatrix() {
}

public static float[][] identity() {
    return new float[][]{{1.0f, 0, 0, 0}, 
            {0, 1.0f, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 1.0f, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 1.0f}};
}

public static float[][] rotateX(float angle) {
    double r = angle * (Math.PI / 180);
    float s = (float)Math.sin(r);
    float c = (float)Math.cos(r);
    return new float[][] {{1, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, c, s, 0},
                        {0, -s, c, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0, 1}};
}

public static float[][] rotateY(float angle) {
    double r = angle * (Math.PI / 180);
    float s = (float)Math.sin(r);
    float c = (float)Math.cos(r);
    return new float[][] {{c, 0, s, 0},
                        {0, 1, 0, 0},
                        {-s, 0, c, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0, 1}};
}

public static float[][] rotateZ(float angle) {
    double r = angle * (Math.PI / 180);
    float s = (float)Math.sin(r);
    float c = (float)Math.cos(r);
    return new float[][] {{c, s, 0, 0},
                        {-s, c, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 1, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0, 1}};
}

public static float[][] scale(float sx, float sy, float sz) {
    float[][] m = identity();
    m[0][0] *= sx;
    m[1][1] *= sy;
    m[2][2] *= sz;
    return m;
}

public static float[][] translate(float tx, float ty, float tz) {
    float[][] m = identity();
    m[3][0] = tx;
    m[3][1] = ty;
    m[3][2] = tz;
    return m;
}

public static float[][] multiply(float [][] a, float[][] b) {
    float[][] m = identity();
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; ++j){
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            m[i][j] = 0;
            for(int k = 0; k < 4; ++k) {
                m[i][j] += a[i][k]*b[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return m;
}

public static FloatBuffer buffer(float[][] m) {
    float[] n = new float[16];
    int k = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            n[k] = m[j][i];
            k++;
        }
    }
    return FloatBuffer.wrap(n);

}

}
```

So in my case I set up individual matrices for translation, scale, and rotations.

so if, for example, I wanted to translate along z, then rotate along y, then scale, I could do:

```
    cgMatrix = gl2.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgID, "cgMatrix");
    float[][] t = CGMatrix.translate(0, 0, 0.5f);
    float[][] s = CGMatrix.scale(1, 0.75f, 1);
    FloatBuffer m = CGMatrix.buffer(CGMatrix.multiply(t, CGMatrix.multiply(ry, s)));
    gl2.glUniformMatrix4fv(cgMatrix, 1, false, m);
```

Where the transformations happen left to right (i.e. first it's translated, then rotated, then scaled)

Anyway, I hope that can be helpful to anyone else!

Thanks for all the responses.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your professor wants you to use your own matrix via glLoadMatrix vice the glTranslate etc.. calls.

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the current shader code:
>
> ```
> [… code example …]
> ```

Please don't compute matrices in the shader. If they're constants the compiler will probably turn them into constants, but it's still very inflexible. The proper way to do this is calculating the matrixes in your main program and then only pass them to OpenGL as uniform. The whole matrix math stuff is straightforward. For C coders I provide https://github.com/datenwolf/linmath.h in the public domain. It should be easy enough to translate this to Java.

Comment: Thank you very much for this link. Between this and a few other resources I finally got it right! I'm about to post the solution in case anyone else can use it in the future. Thanks again!